# How to compile with context without having to re-type the filename in the prompt?

Tags: compiling, context, macports

I would like typeset files with ConTeXt to streamline a document production pipeline, but the `context` script does not work as advertised in the Not So Short Introduction to Context. It leaves me hanging at a prompt (`**`) where I have to type in the input file once again.

```
$ context rain

resolvers       | formats | executing runner 'run luatex format': /opt/local/libexec/texlive/binaries/luatex --jobname="./rain.tex" --fmt=/Users/aljosha/.texlive2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/88aacfe88c3cbee9a12d5f4bec4da90b/formats/luatex/cont-en.fmt --lua=/Users/aljosha/.texlive2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/88aacfe88c3cbee9a12d5f4bec4da90b/formats/luatex/cont-en.lui  --c:currentrun=1 --c:fulljobname="./rain.tex" --c:input="./rain.tex" --c:kindofrun=1 --c:maxnofruns=9 --c:texmfbinpath="/opt/local/libexec/texlive/binaries"
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023/MacPorts 2023.66589_5)
 system commands enabled.
**
```

Whenever I re-type the file name `rain.tex` into the `**` prompt followed by a return the compilation proceeds without issue. Should I wish to integrate conTeXt builds in, say, vim, the present state of affairs is not satisfactory.

`context rain.tex` and `context --luatex rain.tex` both have the same effect

How can I make it work as specified in the manual?

I ran a context --make, which proceeded without error.

Running a `--version` on context gives me the following:

```
$ context --version
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.04
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2023.03.10 12:15
mtx-context     | main context file: /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/mkxl/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2023.03.10 12:15
```

Also:

```
$ luatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023/MacPorts 2023.66589_5)
Development id: 7567

Execute  'luatex --credits'  for credits and version details.

There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is covered by
the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2 or (at your option)
any later version. For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the LuaTeX source.

LuaTeX is Copyright 2022 Taco Hoekwater and the LuaTeX Team.
```

Also:

```
$ luametatex --version
This is LuaMetaTeX, Version 2.10.08

Execute 'luametatex --credits' for credits and version details.

There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is covered by the terms
of the GNU General Public License, version 2 or (at your option) any later
version. For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING
and the LuaMetaTeX source.

Functionality : level 20230426
Support       : context@ntg.nl
Copyright     : The Lua(Meta)TeX Team(s) (2005-2023+)

The LuaMetaTeX project is related to ConTeXt development. This macro package
tightly integrates TeX and MetaPost in close cooperation with Lua. Updates will
happen in sync with ConTeXt and when needed. Don't be fooled by unchanged dates:
long term stability is the objective.
```

All binaries were obtained from TeXlive using `port install`.

Comment: Sorry, I probably missunderstood. So `context rain.tex` works for you, but you want to be able to run `context rain` without `.tex`? (Here in my installation on Linux that works)

Comment: Nope, both don't work for me: the compiler throws me into a shell environment (`**`) where I have to re-type the filename for compilation to proceed. `context rain` and `context rain.tex` both have the same result. Will edit the question for enhanced clarity.

Comment: Your ConTeXt claims that its from TeX Live 2023, but it's running LuaTeX by default for some reason. For TL23+, LuaMetaTeX should be the default, and LMTX handles startup arguments quite differently than LuaTeX, so I suspect that that's the issue. Does `context --luatex <filename>` work for you? And what does `luametatex --version` give?

Comment: `context --luatex rain.tex` gives the same behaviour. `luametatex --version` gives 2.10.8 & `functionality : level 20230426`, amongst other things. See updated question.

Comment: As Max writes, you should in TL23 get luametatex by default. It seems your installation is somehow broken. I would try `https://www.pragma-ade.com/install.htm` or to reinstall what you installed. If you go for something TL based, then maybe wait a few days and get TL24.

Comment: Hmm, what is your `context` pointing to? On Linux, running `realpath $(type -p context)` would show you; macOS should have a similar command to get the target of a symlink. The output should be the path to `luametatex`; if it gives you the path to `luatex` then something weird happened with your installation.

Comment: `$ realpath $(type -p context)` gives
`/opt/local/libexec/texlive/binaries/context`. Macports didn't release TeXlive2024 yet but will wipe my TeX installation and install as it becomes available.

Comment: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Building_LuaMetaTeX_for_TeX_Live gives a few hints, especially that `context` should symlink to `luametatex`. However, when I try and compile with `luametatex` I get the error of `startup error : no format file given, quitting`. Any leads on this?

Comment: LuaMetaTeX acts differently depending on how it's named, so running `luametatex` directly will rarely do anything useful. Try symlinking `mtxrun` and `context` to `luametatex`, then run `mtxrun --generate`, and _hopefully_ everything should be fixed.